# simple theorems that non-mathematicians can understand and appreciate.

Tags: recreational-mathematics, big-list

For example, I stated this fact/theorem at a dinner to some friends and they were pretty impressed.

> Given any sequence of n integers, positive or negative, not
>   necessarily all different, some consecutive subsequence has the
>   property that the sum of the members of the subsequence is a multiple
>   of n.

wording taken from http://www.cut-the-knot.org/pigeonhole/group.shtml

I stated the above in laymans terms so they could understand it and they were interested in it (at least for a few minutes).

What are some other accessible theorems/facts similar to this that non-mathematicians can understand? or maybe simple applications of mathematics that they will understand?

Cheers.

Comment: Community wiki?

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/36711/need-a-result-of-euler-that-is-simple-enough-for-a-child-to-understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Far too many to list! Here are some things that sprang to mind.

- Get a cylindrical glass and draw a line around the outside. Some two diametrically opposite points are at the same height. (Standard Intermediate Value Theorem exercise.)
- If $n$ teams have to play each other exactly once, and can play most one match a day, then the shortest tournament is obviously $n-1$ rounds long if $n$ is even ($n(n-1/2$ matches with at most $n/2$ a day) or $n$ if it is odd. In fact, you can make tournaments of exactly this length. (See [Scheduling a team based activity with 10 different teams and X different games. Every team must meet each other ONCE but never twice,](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/472111/scheduling-a-team-based-activity-with-10-different-teams-and-x-different-games/472176#472176))
- There are lots of good puzzles like http://math.stanford.edu/circle/Summer2012-1-twoinvariants.html with mathematical solutions. This also suggests the simple geometric sum formula which is very neat!
- (Also http://xkcd.com/blue_eyes.html is evil.)

Comment: The cylindrical glass question might also be phrased like this: I leave my house at 8 AM and walk to my grandmother's house, arriving at 8 PM.  The next day I say goodbye at 8 AM and depart, arriving home by the same route at 8 PM.  There is at least one point during the journey when I was at the exact same place at the exact same time of day on the two days.

Answer (score 6):

Stir a cup of tea, but don't let your spoon touch the walls of the cup. Once the tea has settled, there is some point in the liquid which is in exactly the same place in the cup as before you stirred it.

This is a consequence of the [Brouwer Fixed Point Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brouwer_fixed-point_theorem).

Comment: Is stirring tea really going to be a continuous function?  I usually describe this theorem as cutting a circle from a piece of paper, wrinkling & stretching it, and then pressing it back into the hole (it tends to be more fun as most people will then try to "break" the theorem by describing ways of doing it, and you can help them find the fixed point in each one).

Comment: Well, if you have a suitably viscous tea...

Answer (score 2):

The [Ham sandwich theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ham_sandwich_theorem) is fun. If you have something (a ham sandwich) consisting of three pieces of any shape, then it's always possible to cut it with one single straight cut into two ham sandwiches, in such a way that all three pieces are equally divided between the sandwiches.

Answer (score 2):

Every sphere which sprouts hair [has a quiff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairy_ball_theorem).

Answer (score 2):

I think the proof that irrational numbers exist is easy to understand the fact is quite interesting.

**Theorem**: Not all numbers can be expressed as decimal fractions

**Proof**: Suppose you could write $\sqrt{2}$ as a completely shortened number, that means it exists $p,q \in \mathbb{N}$ such that

$\begin{align}\sqrt{2} &= \frac{p}{q}\\
\Leftrightarrow 2 &= \frac{p^2}{q^2}\\
\Leftrightarrow 2 q^2 &= p^2
\end{align}$

But this means that $p^2$ is even which means that $p$ is even. So we can write $p$ as $p = 2r$:

$\begin{align}2 q^2 &= p^2\\
\Leftrightarrow 2q^2 &= (2r)^2\\
\Leftrightarrow 2q^2 &= 4r^2\\
\Leftrightarrow q^2 &= 2r^2
\end{align}$

This means that $q$ is also even. So both, $p$ and $q$ have $2$ as a factor. This means $\sqrt{2}$ cannot be written as a completely shortened fraction. As every rational number can be written as a completely shortened fraction, $\sqrt{2}$ cannot be a rational number $\blacksquare$

---

Also very interesting:

- Birthday paradox (which can easily be explained with the pigeonhole principle)
- Seven Bridges of Königsberg: Eulers Theorem (A graph has a Eulerian cycle $\Leftrightarrow$ Every vertex has an even degree). You might also find interesting theorems in this presentation which I made as an [introduction to graph theory](https://github.com/MartinThoma/LaTeX-examples/tree/master/presentations/Diskrete-Mathematik/LaTeX).

Answer (score 1):

I very much like [Sylvester–Gallai theorem](http://e-math.ams.org/samplings/feature-column/fcarc-sylvester1):

> Given a finite number of points in the Euclidean plane, either
>
> 1. All the points are collinear; or
> 2. there is a line which contains exactly two of the points.

[Kelly's proof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%E2%80%93Gallai_theorem#Kelly.27s_proof) of this theorem is a real mathematical gem.

Answer (score 1):

[God's number is 20](http://www.cube20.org/): Every position of Rubik's cube can be solved in at most 20 moves.

[R(3,3)=6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theorem_on_friends_and_strangers): In any party of six people either at least three of them are (pairwise) mutual strangers or at least three of them are (pairwise) mutual acquaintances.

Answer (score 0):

Take a beachball and deflate it, then flatten it against the ground, as wrinkled and stretched out as you like (but not torn).  There will then always be two opposite points of the beachball pressed against the same point on the ground (the [Borsuk-Ulam theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borsuk%E2%80%93Ulam_theorem)).

Another fun way to phrase the theorem is that at any given time, two completely opposite ends of the earth have the exact same temperature and pressure.

Comment: For temperature and pressure, why should the pair of antipodal points be the same?

Comment: @AlexR. Temperature and pressure are both 1-dimensional values.  The map from the surface of the earth to the pair (temperature, pressure) is a map $S^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$, thus has a pair of antipodal points with the same values in $\mathbb{R}^2$, thus both the same temperature and same pressure.